# Groovy - custom script class using CompilerConfiguration. Property setter idiom on Script object does not work

Tags: groovy, eval

Here's the example that the [Groovy doc](http://www.groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) essentially has for creating custom script classes then instantiating a GroovyShell object with a CompilerConfiguration object that references that custom Script class:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

abstract class MyScript extends Script {
    String name
    String greet() {
       "Hello, $name"
    }
}

def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.scriptBaseClass = 'MyScript'
shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), config)
script = shell.parse('greet()')
assert script instanceof MyScript
script.setName('Foo')
assert script.run() == 'Hello, Foo'
```

Now when I change `script.setName('Foo')` to `script.name = 'Foo'`:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

abstract class MyScript extends Script {
    String name
    String greet() {
       "Hello, $name"
    }
}

def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
config.scriptBaseClass = 'MyScript'
shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), config)
script = shell.parse('greet()')
assert script instanceof MyScript
script.name = 'Foo'
assert script.run() == 'Hello, Foo'
```

it breaks things with the following output:

```
Caught: Assertion failed: 

assert script.run() == 'Hello, Foo'
       |      |     |
       |      |     false
       |      Hello, null
       Script1@243c4f91

Assertion failed: 

assert script.run() == 'Hello, Foo'
       |      |     |
       |      |     false
       |      Hello, null
       Script1@243c4f91

   at bar.run(bar.groovy:16)
```

which clearly shows that Groovy property access idiom does not work for this case. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Just tried your script [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5126658050752512) and it works fine.

Comment: @Rao, whoops, let me edit my question so that it's more readable. What doesn't work is when you try to do `script.name = 'Foo'` rather than `script.setName('Foo')` explicitly.